# How to debug file download WebView code that is causing a corrupted file?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-download-manager

I am a newbie in Android app development. I have done this for downloading a documents in my webview.

I want to download the file but it is downloading some corrupted file.  I had added the required permissions in **manifest.xml**.

```
private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {

        boolean value = true;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            if (mimeType != null) {
                if (mimeType.toLowerCase().contains("pdf")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("ppt")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("doc")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("rar")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("rtf")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("exe")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("apk")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("jpeg")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("png")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("xls")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("zip")
                        || extension.toLowerCase().contains("jpg")) {
                    DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    String name= URLUtil.guessFileName(url,null,MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
                  File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),name);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..");
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                   // request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,name);
                   mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    //value = false;
                }
            }
            if (value) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: How is it corrupted? Empty? Truncated? Wrong contents? Do you see any errors in your LogCat? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Please change the title of the post to include a minimal summary of the problem and no more.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Posts here should not ask for, or imply a desire for, other people to do your work for you. Stack Overflow, and indeed any other volunteer forum on the web, is not a place where you can order free labour. Readers will be happy to help, but it needs to be you doing the actual work.

Comment: Thankyou... It just downloads a file of size 12.65kb with ppt, orpdf extensions but  when I try to open that file it's returning file is corrupted. Can anyone debug this. Thanks in advance